# ElasticSearch: Mapping not applied to AWS ELK

Tags: java, elasticsearch

while applying below mapping to my local ElasticSearch 7.4.1

```
private static void addIndexMapping(RestHighLevelClient client, String indexName) throws IOException {
        PutMappingRequest request = new PutMappingRequest(indexName);
        XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
        builder.startObject();
        {
            builder.startObject("properties");
            {
                builder.startObject("modifiedDate");
                {
                    builder.field("type", "date").field("format","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

                }
                builder.endObject();
            }
            builder.endObject();
        }
        builder.endObject();
        request.source(builder);
        client.indices().putMapping(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    }
```

i can see below mapping got created

```
{
  "sandbox" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "modifiedDate" : {
        "full_name" : "modifiedDate",
        "mapping" : {
          "modifiedDate" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but when applying same mapping on AWS elk 7.4.2 i am seeing below mapping

```
{
  "sandbox" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "modifiedDate" : {
        "full_name" : "modifiedDate",
        "mapping" : {
          "modifiedDate" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my local i have installed ElasticSearch 7.4.1 and in production ElasticSearch 7.4.2. Couldn't understand what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Hi, Do you add both mappings using the code? just changing the client from local to AWS?

Comment: @saeednasehi, yes i added both mapping using the code.

Comment: In my view, you add some data before you create your mapping. this type of mapping is created when you don't have mapping and it is created when the first document inserted. Are you sure that no document inserted before you create mapping?

Comment: Both index and mapping will be created when first document insert happens.

Comment: Yes, you are right. but if you don't create your index and mapping before inserting the first document, elasticsearch creates mapping which is not suitable for you. You need to create your index and mapping before you insert your first data.

Comment: same piece of code in my local how come i am seeing proper mapping.

Comment: Maybe you have been using index template [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-templates.html) in your local.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223147/discussion-between-teamz-and-saeednasehi).

Comment: @saeednasehi, your answer resolved my issue.

Comment: Great!. Happy to hear that. So If you allow me to send that result as an answer for further usages on this question.

Comment: Please do that.

Comment: @saeednasehi i need your help on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65005817/kibana-index-pattern-dont-show-data-with-time-filter-field-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that you create your mapping in local before inserting first document. If you don't do this, you probably are using template in your local elasticsearch. You can see more information about templates [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html). In your case, templates would be something look like this:

```
PUT _index_template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": ["te*", "bar*"],
  "template": {
  "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
          "modifiedDate": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
          }
       }
   }
}
}
```